# LINQ to return null if an array is empty

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

```
public class Stuff
{
  public int x;
  // ... other stuff
}
```

I have a `IEnumerable<Stuff>` and I want to build a `int[]` of all of the `x` properties of all the `Stuff` objects in the collection.

I do:

```
IEnumerable<Stuff> coll;
// ...
var data = coll.Select(s => s.x).ToArray();
```

What I want is a null array rather than a `int[0]` if the collection is empty.  In other words, if `!coll.Any()`, then I want `data = null`.  (My actual need is that `coll` is an intermediate result of a complex LINQ expression, and I would like to do this with a LINQ operation on the expression chain, rather than saving the intermediate result)

I know that `int[0]` is more desirable than `null` in many contexts, but I am storing many of these results and would prefer to pass around `nulls` than empty arrays.

So my current solution is something like:

```
var tmp = coll.Select(s => s.x).ToArray();
int[] data = tmp.Any() ? tmp : null;
```

Any way to do this without storing `tmp`?

**EDIT**: The main question is how to do this without storing intermediate results.  Something like `NULLIF()` from `T-SQL` where you get back what you passed in if the condition is false, and `NULL` if the condition is true.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're doing this a lot, you could write an extension method:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt
{
    public static T[] ToArrayOrNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        var result = seq.ToArray();

        if (result.Length == 0)
            return null;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then your calling code would be:

```
var data = coll.Select(s => s.x).ToArrayOrNull();
```

Comment: I like this approach very much.  You could also add a check for `seq == null` if you wanted null safety, unlike my previous solution.

Answer (score 3):

Create the array only if `coll` is not empty, so the other way round:

```
int[] data = null;
if(coll.Any()) data = coll.Select(s => s.x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way to get `Select` to return null, but if you don't want to create an additional *array* you could do:

```
var tmp = coll.Select(s => s.x);
int[] data = tmp.Any() ? tmp.ToArray() : null;
```

Comment: Why iterate the results twice, instead of what OP currently has ?

Comment: `Any()` will return immediately either because the projection is empty or has at least one element, so it's not enumerating the entire collection twice.

Comment: But if `coll` is a "LINQ to SQL" or other heavy-lifting expression, it will do the work twice, and may potentially even be inconsistent between executions.